# Select text in nested ng-repeat in protractor

Tags: angularjs, timeout, angularjs-ng-repeat, protractor

I have a nested list of suggestions below a search box that looks like this:

```
<div class="type-row clearfix" data-ng-class="suggestion_type.klass" data-ng-repeat="suggestion_type in searchBoxData.suggestion_types">
  <div class="type-name-wrapper" data-ng-show="suggestion_type.contents.length > 0">
    <div class="type-name small semi-bold">{{suggestion_type.name}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="type-content" data-ng-show="suggestion_type.contents.length > 0">
    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="content in suggestion_type.contents" data-ng-class="{ selected: content.selected}" data-ng-mouseover="searchBoxData.selectSuggestion($parent.$index, $index)">
        <div class="row-wrapper light clearfix" data-ng-click="searchBoxData.submitQuery($event);">
          <div data-ng-bind-html="content.category_string"></div>
          <div data-ng-bind-html="content.other_string"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

For instance, I wanna write an integration test that would check for the number of displayed suggestions and which type of suggestions are displayed first.

I started to write a test using protactor. It's not finished yet as I am struggling to understand the output from the console.logs. So far it looks like this:

```
describe('autocomplete display', function(){

  it('displays 2 results for categories and 2 results for task on -plu- search input ', function(){
    var searchBox = element(by.id("inputAnimation"));
    searchBox.sendKeys("plu").then(function(){

      element.all(by.repeater('suggestion_type in searchBoxData.suggestion_types')).then(function(rows) {
        console.log(rows);

        for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
          rows[i].getText().then(function(foo){
            console.log(foo);
          });
          rows[i].then(function(row){
            row.findElements(by.binding('suggestion_type.name')).then(function(res){
              res[0].getText().then(function(name){
                console.log(name);
              });

            });


          });
        }
      });

    });
  });
});
```

One problem with it is that there is no timeout so the server does not always have time to send me the results. The other problem is that I am not understanding why `foo` seem to match all the text bound to the suggestion_type object in the ng-repeat. Any help would be appreciated.